# nonlinear systems of differential equations stable points with complex coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve this system of differential equations.

\begin{cases}
x_1'= -x_1+2x_1^3+x_2,\\
x_2'= x_1+x_1x_2.
\end{cases}
*by abusing the notations, I assumed $x(t) = x$

Among fixed points, some of them have complex coordinates. What do these points mean?
Should I take them into account when describing the system's behavior?

Comment: Hi there, it's a little hard to understand what you're writing as you haven't used MathsJax. I've supplied a link here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @MiladYekani: Do you mean numerically, trying to find the phase portrait, or trying to find a closed-form solution?

Comment: I am trying numerically to find phase portrait. for this, I search for the points that x1' and x2' are zero then I try to evaluate the behavior of the system in the vicinity

Comment: The problem is I get some points with complex coordinates (x1 or x2 by real and imaginary parts) what should I do by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to math.stackexchange

Typically $x_1$ and $x_2$ are real variables so they never take on complex values.

Complex values are not stable points for real variables.

$\dot{x_1} = -x_1+2x_1^3+x_2$

$\dot{x_2} =  x_1+x_1x_2$

For $\dot{x_1} = 0$ you have $x_2 = x_1 - 2x_1^3$

For $\dot{x_2} = 0$ you have $x_1+x_1x_2 = 0$ either $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = -1$
[image: quiver plot]

octave:

```
[x1, x2] = meshgrid(-1.5:0.1:1.5, -1.5:0.1:1.5);
x1dot = -x1 + 2*x1.^3 + x2;
x2dot =  x1 + x1.*x2;
quiver(x1,x2,x1dot, x2dot,"color","blue");
title("x1dot = -x1 + 2*x1^3 + x2;  x2dot =  x1 + x1.*x2;");
hold on;
xx1 = [-1.1:0.1:1.1];
xx2 = xx1 - 2*xx1.^3;

plot(xx1,xx2,"color","red");
line([0 0], [ -1.5 1.5], "color", "green");
line([-1.5 1.5] , [-1 -1] , "color", "green");

legend(" ","x1dot = 0","xdot2  = 0");
```

The red line is  $\dot{x_1} = 0$. The green lines are  $\dot{x_2} = 0$.

The steady points are the intercepts at $(x_1,x_2) = $ $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks indeed. The code was so useful. Although my main question is why these points appear and what they mean, I think the issue is more fundamental. I should try to get a more profound intuition of imaginary roots and solve my problem in another domain.it's like, " If these points are not interacting with the real world, Why I need them."
But your solution was the answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: Milad Yekani - in control systems of real signals complex roots always occur in conjugate pairs $r = -x \pm iy$. These typically translate into a decay term $e^{-xt}$ and an oscillation term $e^{iyt} \pm e^{-iyt}$ which is a cos or sin term. $y(t) = e^{-xt}(e^{iyt} \pm e^{-iyt})$. A purely complex pair of roots forms an oscillator. $\frac{(e^{iyt} + e^{-iyt})}{2} = cos(yt)$ and  $\frac{(e^{iyt} - e^{-iyt})}{2i} = sin(yt)$.

Comment: Thanks, Arthur, but I know nothing about signal control. Honestly, I am somebody so naive trying to understand calculus. Let us try another way. I know at first, these unknown numbers have appeared in cubic equations. Back then, what made those people think about these problems (a real-life application, I mean). How they overcame the complexity when this question raised, "what does this complex root have to do in our real-life problem?" 

If I am asking a wrong question or asking in a lousy way or maybe asking it under not fitting tag, please help me to fix it.

Comment: Milad Yekani - The hypotenuse of a triangle is not always a rational number. The roots of polynomials produced $\sqrt{-1}$. Continued fractions produced irrational and transcendental numbers etc.. Number theory books cover most of these topics. It took genius mathematicians like Gauss and centuries to clarify concepts. Today there is too much for one person to understand it all.